# FTP Connection Confirmation Required in Bash Script

Tags: ftp, ksh

I am using the below code to connect with ftp node. I just want to know that how would I check if I am unable to connect with ftp server or ftp server is not responding. In any case it would alert me ftp server is ok or down. Actually I want to embed the normal bash code for checking of connectivity.

```
#!/bin/ksh  
ftp -nv <<EOF  
open xxx.xx.xx.xx  
user xxx xxxxxxxxx  
bye  
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

How about grepping the output from ftp?  I'm not sure what your version of ftp returns when it's done a successful upload, but something like:

```
#!/bin/ksh

(
ftp -nv <<EOF
open xxx.xx.xx.xx
user xxx xxxxxxxxx
bye
EOF
) | grep -i "success"
if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]
then
        echo "FTP SUCCESS"
else
        echo "FTP FAIL"
fi
```

Should work..

Comment: giving the following error                               
./noini.sh[3]: syntax error at line 3 : `<<' unmatched

Comment: Hmm, might be a difference between bash and ksh (which I don't have) simple scripts are usually compatible but perhaps not in this case.

Comment: Your code works in my environment. @Dogar : Be sure there are not hidden chars (space, tab, ??) after both copies of the `EOF` . Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem before, solved it with checking the output from the ftp command. Still, found it quite weird, so i decided to use PERL for it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::FTP;

# open connection
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new("127.0.0.1");
if (! $ftp) {
    print "connection failed!";
    exit 1;
}

# in case you would need to test login too
# if (! $ftp->login("username", "password")) {
#    print "login failed!";
#    exit 2;
#}

$ftp->close();
exit 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to check whether an ftp-server is available:

`sleep 1 | telnet ftp.example.com 21 2> /dev/null | grep -c 'FTP'`

What it does:

- Establishes a connection to ftp.example.com via port 21 (use port 22 for sftp)
- Waits one second and then terminates the connection
- Ignores the "Connection closed by remote host"-response from telnet with "2> /dev/null"
- Returns "1" if the response from the addressed server contains "FTP" and "0" if it does not.

You might have to adjust the grep pattern 'FTP' if the expected welcome response from the ftp server you want to check differs from the standard response, which usually reads something like this:

```
   Trying 93.184.216.34...
   Connected to ftp.example.com.
   Escape character is '^]'.
   220 FTP Service
```